# How can I format the string `00:00:30:00` to TimeSpan?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I receive a date-time from automation system like this: `00:00:30:00`.

When I try to parse it to `TimeSpan` I get this error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

What kind of format can help me to convert this to `TimeSpan`?

Comment: Do you mean to ask how to _parse_ the string to a `TimeSpan`?

Comment: You could also alternatively use the `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)` or `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)` calls to create a new timespan structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decent TimeSpan parsing is only available in .NET 4.0.  For earlier version you can hijack the DateTime parsing methods, converting from a date to a timespan through the Ticks property.  Like this:

```
    public static bool TryParseTime(string txt, string fmt, out TimeSpan ts) {
        DateTime dt;
        bool ok = DateTime.TryParseExact(txt, fmt, null, 
            System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out dt);
        ts = new TimeSpan(ok ? dt.Ticks : 0);
        return ok;
    }
```

Additional work is required when you need to parse negative time spans.

Comment: this is what i'am looking for, because i'am new in this forum. now the descussion is closed.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [custom TimeSpan format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) together with the [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parseexact.aspx) methods:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact("00:00:30:00", 
                                  "hh:mm:ss:ff", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

If you don't want to risk the possible format exception, you can use the [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tryparseexact.aspx) methods - these require an out parameter and return a boolean indicating if the parse succeeded or not.